# Flutter Provider-Consumer EXCEPTION error

Tags: flutter, dart

the code was working fine a few weeks ago, and then suddenly I get this in my log.

I/flutter (14128): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY

I/flutter (14128): The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building Consumer(dirty):

I/flutter (14128): Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this Consumer Widget

I/flutter (14128):   Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
I/flutter (14128):   other routes will not be able to access that provider.

I/flutter (14128): - You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

I/flutter (14128):   Make sure that Consumer is under your MultiProvider/Provider.

I/flutter (14128):   This usually happen when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

I/flutter (14128):   For example, instead of:

```
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Provider<Example>(
    create: (_) => Example(),
    // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
    // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
     child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
     ),
  }
```

I/flutter (14128):   consider using `builder` like so:

```
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Provider<Example>(
   create: (_) => Example(),
   // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
   builder: (context) {
   // No longer throws
   return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
   }
   ),
   }
```

I/flutter (14128): If none of these solutions work, consider asking for help on StackOverflow:

I/flutter (14128): The relevant error-causing widget was:

I/flutter (14128):   Consumer

I/flutter (14128):   /lib/custom_widgets/favorite_widget.dart:18:12

I/flutter (14128): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

I/flutter (14128): #0      Provider._inheritedElementOf (package:provider/src/provider.dart:309:7)

I/flutter (14128): #1      Provider.of (package:provider/src/provider.dart:261:30)

I/flutter (14128): #2      Consumer.buildWithChild (package:provider/src/consumer.dart:177:16)
═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

I/flutter (14128): Another exception was thrown: Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this

This is how it is (current)

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Consumer<FavoriteModel>(
    builder: (context, house, child) => IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
```

And this is after I changed it to try and fix it by following the method in the error (but doesnt work)

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Provider<FavoriteModel>(
  create: (_FavoriteWidgetState) => FavoriteModel,
    builder: (context, house, child) {
    return Text(context.watch<FavoriteModel>());
    IconButton(
          onPressed: ()
```

Answer (score 1):

check this solution, that work for me :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Place Event',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: primary,
      ),
      home: Consumer<Datas>(
        builder: (context, datas, child){
          try {
            return RootApp();
          } catch (e){
            return Text('Error');
          }

        },
      )
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a ChangeNotifier in your main.dart file.
Like in the following example:

````
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// wrap MaterialApp in Provider widget
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => YourModel(), // ← create/init your state model
      child: MaterialApp(
          home: ScreenA()
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````